# Open current page in w3m in firefox?

Tags: firefox, w3m

I've been using w3m lately to browse the web, but sometimes I want to view the page in firefox instead. Is there a way to open the current page in w3m in firefox with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While in w3m, type `o` to open the Option Setting Panel. Scroll down to the External Program Settings section and the External Browser line. In the text field on the right, enter `firefox`. Move to the `[OK]` box a few lines down and hit Enter.

Now, if you're on a page you want to view using Firefox, just type `M`. To follow a link using Firefox, type `<Esc>M`.

You can also add second and third external browsers if you want to use something else in addition to Firefox.

Comment: thanks. I had to change the line in External Program Settings from /usr/bin/mozilla to /usr/bin/firefox and that did the trick